# C++ SHGetFolderPath issue

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the local 'Program files' dir path and append some extra path to it and simply execute it. Can't get it to work properly..

This is my current code:

```
wchar_t* localAppData = 0;
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86, 0, NULL, &localAppData);

wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << L"/MyApp/MyExe.exe";

CreateProcess(static_cast<void*>(localAppData));
```

I'm getting this for teh SHGetFolderPath:

```
cannot convert parameter 5 from wchar_t ** to LPWSTR
```

Also, even though I've included sstream in the headers, I'm getting these errors:

```
'wstringstream' : undeclared identifier
```

Note: I'm using SHGetFolderPath as I need this to work on both XP and Vista/7

**EDIT:**

Had a mistake in the code above, I was trying to run `localAppData` which is the path to the 'Program Files' directory, instead of running the entire path.

But when I try using the `ss` var instead of `localAppData` var in the `CreateProcess` function, I'm getting an error about using the wrong type of var (need to be using LPCWSTR).

But when I try this, doesn't work as well.. No error but application is not running, what am I missing?

```
wchar_t localAppData[MAX_PATH];
STARTUPINFO sInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86, 0, NULL, localAppData);

std::wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << L"/MyApp/MyExe.exe";
LPCWSTR str = ss.str().c_str();
CreateProcess(str, NULL,NULL, NULL,FALSE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&sInfo,&pInfo);
return str;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wchar_t localAppData[MAX_PATH];
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86, 0, NULL, localAppData);
std::wstringstream ss;
```

1. SHGetFolderPath requires pointer to caller-allocated array, and fills it with resulting path.
2. Don't forget about std namespace.

Comment: Sorry, it is difficult to understand what is the problem now. Maybe you can post a new question with your current code, without history.

Comment: Also, situation "No error but application is not running" means that you don't check return value of the function called. Please provide more information.

Comment: I've updated the question with the entire code.. I'm returning the final path, but this whole thing is a part of a Firebreath project that is producing a DLL that is included in a Chrome extension..

Answer (score 1):

`SHGetFolderPath` is not going to allocate a buffer for you and change the value of `localAppData`, so it doesn't accept a `wchar_t**` like you are passing it here. You need to allocate the buffer yourself, for example:

```
whar_t localAppData[MAX_PATH];
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86, 0, NULL, localAppData);
```

As for the `wstringstream`, are you `using namespace std;`? If not, you need to specify the type as `std::wstringstream`.

Comment: You're off by one, MAX_PATH already includes the terminating zero.  No harm done but not technically correct.

Comment: @HansPassant: Didn't quite remember so I thought to play it safe. Thanks for the reminder.